# How to pass multiple columns in setLabelCol to xgboost in spark mllib?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, xgboost

I am trying to train an xgboost algorithm in scala spark and using multi label classification. I have made a vector of input columns and output columns

```
val vectorAssembler1 = new VectorAssembler().
                        setInputCols(Array("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5")).
                        setOutputCol("features")
val inputFeaturesVecDF = vectorAssembler1.transform(inputDF).
                                                   select("features","label1","label2","label3","label4")

val vectorAssembler2 = new VectorAssembler().
                        setInputCols(Array("label1","label2","label3","label4")).
                        setOutputCol("labels")
val xgbInputDF = vectorAssembler2.transform(inputFeaturesVecDF).select("features","labels")
```

I instantiate the model as below and run fit on it

```
val xgbClassifier = new XGBoostClassifier().
                        setFeaturesCol("features").
                        setLabelCol("labels").
                        setObjective("multi:softmax").
                        setMaxDepth(3).
                        setNumClass(4).
                        setNumRound(10).
                        setNumWorkers(8)
val xgbClassificationModel = xgbClassifier.fit(xgbInputDF)
```

When I run it I get the following error. Any help will be appreciated

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Column labels must be of type numeric but was actually of type struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>.`

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, are you able to figure out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

XGboost does not offer multi label classification.